# Width not changing with JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the width of an item with JS, but its not working for some reason. Here's what I'm using `$('.top').css('width', bad + '%');` heres the full code

```
 var bad = 0;
var cback=function(){
  bad=0;
  $('.form :text').each(function (i,e) {
      if ($.trim($(e).val()) == "") bad++;   
    });
  $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing(Completed '+count()+')');
  //else $('.congrats').hide();
}

$(document).delegate('.form :text','focus',cback);
$(document).delegate('.form :text','keyup',cback)

function count(){
  console.log("Total inputs " + $('.form :text').length);
  //Divide by complete inputs out of 100% and get percent
  console.log("The percentage is " + bad / $('.form :text').length + "%");

  return 100-(bad / $('.form :text').length)*100 + "%"
};

$('.top').css('width', bad + '%');
```

And when I look at the HTMl all I get is `style="width: 0%;"` Any ideas?

Comment: the only code changing your `bad` is `if ($.trim($(e).val()) == "") bad++;`, but it's still `0` -> that means you don't have any **empty** text field.

Comment: But it returns an integer. So its not zero. `console.log` proves it too @KingKing

Comment: check for 'bad' just before you set width if it returns a value, i dont know where you have checked it as you said it returns integer value in above comment. create a fiddle if possible

Answer (score 0):

bad is being set in the css method before your the each() actually runs.  Javascript isn't synchronous so as the each() method completes `$(".top").css("width, bad + "%")` will have already been set.  So will need to move that bit of code to the end of your cback function.

Edit:
Looking at some more the issue doesn't matter if sync or async or not.  Your cback function is only called when certain events happen.  When those event fire off, they update bad but bad has already been set in the css long before any of the events can be triggered.  Even when they get triggered the css never gets updated with the new bad value.  This is why the code to set the css should be moved into the cback function.

Comment: I'm not sure if `.each` is asynchronous or not, but if so it should show `0` (or some value not `1000`) in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LCSEj/) ?

Comment: @KingKing - You are correct but it doesn't matter as the OP is setting the width before the cback function is ever called and then only updates bad in cback and never changes the width to the new bad value.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood it, in fact the `.each` is placed in a callback function but I did not see it and thought it's placed outside (and of course it would run immediately). It's because of the OP's code format (which is too terrible).

Answer (score 0):

variable bad is set to 0 outside cback function where you set width of .top element, you need to set width within the function.

```
    var bad = 0;
var cback=function(){
    bad=0;
    $('.form :text').each(function (i,e) {
        if ($.trim($(e).val()) == "") bad++;
    });
    $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing(Completed '+count()+')');
    $('.top').css('width', bad + '%');
}
$(document).delegate('.form :text','focus',cback);
$(document).delegate('.form :text','keyup',cback)

function count(){
    console.log("Total inputs " + $('.form :text').length);
    //Divide by complete inputs out of 100% and get percent
    console.log("The percentage is " + bad / $('.form :text').length + "%");
    return 100-(bad / $('.form :text').length)*100 + "%"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
$('.form :text').each(function (i,e) {
  if ($.trim($(e).val()) == "") bad++;
```

To

```
$('.form :text').each(function () {
  if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") bad++;
```

since your each operate on jQuery objects and not an array